# Time series model in production - Re-train on the fly as as batch process?

Tags: r, time-series, large-data, exponential-smoothing, online-algorithms

Let's say I've a time series of phone calls per day over the last three years. I could train a model using exponential smoothing (e.g. HoltWinters) for predicting the future amount of phone calls per day. I want to use this model in an interactive dashboard, that visualize the phone data of the past as well as the prediction for the next 10 days.

Of course the data set grows with every day, because every day new phone calls are received. My first approach was to train the model on the fly, therefore every time the dashboard is opened.
This doesn't seem to be a good option because the data set is pretty large. In other ML projects I used batch processing and re-trained the model periodically. Is this also an option for time series, even if the time series has already changed after one day? If yes, at what intervals should the forecast model of the time series be retrained?

Comment: Since exponential smoothing models can be represented as state-space models, it should be computationally cheap to update the parameter estimates (and then the forecasts) online / on the fly (i.e. with every new data point that arrives).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is basically train the model for example once a day (depending on the interval), save it and append its forecasts to a copy of the array you're storing your data in so all of it could be easily accessed. You can set the border on the dashboard basing on the index in the array (i.e. 5 periods ahead forecast -> border 5 indexes before the end).

You can retrain your model in time series (in some cases you even should). A lot depends on the actual model and actual data here, I cannot give you a strict yes or not answer, however if you're retraining the model you need to be careful with the parameters your model is using and with the statistical properties of the time series (the old and the new one) you're dealing with.